# Keep settings of controls in an inner scope when changing control in an outer scope

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I learnt about [Temporal motivation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_motivation_theory) from my friend. So I tried to plot something like this:

```
DynamicModule[{n}, 
  Manipulate[
    n, 
    {n, 1, 10}, 
    Dynamic[With[{t = n}, 
      Manipulate[
        Plot[(ε V)/(1 + Γ D), {D, 0, t}], 
      {V, 0, 5}, 
      {Γ, 0, 1}, 
      {ε, 0, 5}]]]
```

Whenever `n` is changed, the inner `Manipulate`'s sliders get reset. How can I keep this from happening?

[image]

Comment: why all this complication for? Why not just use Manipulate as normally it is meant to be used? What is wrong with `Manipulate[
 Plot[(\[CurlyEpsilon] V)/(1 + \[CapitalGamma] D), {D, 0, n}],
 {V, 0, 5},
 {\[CapitalGamma], 0, 1},
 {\[CurlyEpsilon], 0, 5},
 {n, 1, 10}
 ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you change `n`, the inner `Manipulate` expression gets re-evaluated, so of course all its variables, which in this case are all controls, get reinitialized. The way to fix it is to get rid of the nesting and have only one `Manipulate` expression, You don't need the outer `DynamicModule` either (a `Manipulate` expression is transformed into a dynamic module when it is evaluated, so your code produces three nested levels of dynamic modules.)

So what you need is much simpler than what you wrote.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[(ε V)/(1 + Γ D), {D, 0, n}],
  {{n, 5}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{V, 2}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{Γ, .5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{ε, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Notes

- Instead of having `n` displayed in a panel, I use the option `Appearance` to display its value on the right-hand side of its slider. I do the same for the other controls because I think it is almost always good make the current value of the controls visible.
- Presuming that `n` is meant to represent an integer variable, I have constrained its slider to step by 1.
- I have added explicit initialization to all the controls.